# What if I change the region in the Nintendo 3DS settings?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, region-lock

I know that the Nintendo 3DS is region-locked. It will not let me play out of my region games. But there is an option of changing the region in the Nintendo 3DS's setting. If I change the region there will it allow me to play the games of that region too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, **no**.

That setting will only change [eShop region](https://nintenpedia.com/how-to-change-nintendo-3ds-eshop-region/).
This will let you access different software listings on the shop, but you won't be able to play physical copies from that specific region. You are tied with the one you have.

Comment: But what if you move to another country with thee 3ds?

Comment: the 3DS. Grammar error

Comment: @Deer492 it will still only run games from the same region as before. It's not something related to your actual location in the world, it's set in 3DS firmware

Comment: Thank you for this. I am grateful to you. The truth is I live in Bangladesh. My uncle came from the UK and gave my cousin a European 3DS. My cousin gave it to me. But most of my friends use the US version. My family is not that rich. In my country, the UK game cards cost twice the price of the US version. For example, The US version costs BDT 2,500 and the UK version costs BDT 4,000. It is a lot for us. So I thought of using games of my friends. But now it is not possible. Still, thank you a lot.

Comment: @ShadmanHaque glad to help. Keep in mind that it could be possible to [remove region lock from a 3DS](https://www.reddit.com/r/3DS/comments/4qyfej/is_there_any_way_to_remove_region_locking_from_a/) using Homebrew or installing a custom firmware, which falls under hacking the system so I wouldn't suggest it. It's definitely viable though, but I can't help for this.